# jQuery Flotcharts - show grid lines?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, flot

I'm using http://www.flotcharts.org/. Why do my grid lines disappear?

[image: flot without grid lines]

Here is code for my plot options:

```
var options = {
        grid: {
            markings: EVS,
            clickable: true,
            hoverable: true
        },
        series: {
            lines: {
                show: true,
                fill: true,
                lineWidth: 1,
                fillColor: {
                    colors: [{
                        opacity: 1
                    }, {
                        opacity: 1
                    }]
                }
            }
        },
        colors: ["rgba(41, 150, 206, 0.9)", "rgba(67, 90, 110, 0.4)", "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"],
        crosshair: {
            mode: "xy",
            color: "#323232",
            lineWidth: 1
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: mode,
            show: true,
            position: "bottom",
            color: "#323232",
            font: {
                size: 10,
                lineHeight: 15
            },
            labelHeight: 15,
            tickLength: 5
        },
        yaxis: {
            show: true,
            position: "left",
            color: "#323232",
            labelWidth: 20,
            font: {
                size: 10
            },
            max: vmax + 20,
            min: 0,
            minTickSize: 1,
            tickSize:20,
            tickLength: 10
        },
        pan: {
            interactive: true,
            cursor: "move",
            frameRate: 60
        },
        tooltip: true,
        tooltipOpts: {
            id: 'flotTip', //"flotTip"
            content: '%x : %y km/h', //"%s | X: %x | Y: %y"
            shifts: {
                x: 10, //10
                y: 20 //20
            },
            defaultTheme: true, //true
            lines: {
                track: true, //false
                threshold: 0.01 //0.05
            },
            onHover: function (flotItem, $tooltipEl) {
                if (flotItem.seriesIndex == 1) $tooltipEl[0].innerHTML = "Postój";
            }
        }
    };
```

I just want simple yaxis lines.

PS. The crosshair is from the crosshair plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the `tickLength` option if you want to have the lines at the ticks. Flot doesn't have "grid lines" per se, but tick lines which can run through the grid. If you only want them on one axis, set the option on one axis but not the other.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) (emphasis mine):

> "tickLength" is the length of the tick lines in pixels. **By default, the innermost axes will have ticks that extend all across the plot**, while any extra axes use small ticks. A value of null means use the default, **while a number means small ticks of that length** - set it to 0 to hide the lines completely.